# Sideloading ipa using ideviceinstaller

Tags: linux, installation, ipa, cydia, sideloading

I tried to install ipa using linux machine. I never done this before and got this error.

[SIdeloading ipa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cP0bL.png)

Comment: Even I am getting same error, have you found any solution for this?
In my case I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and iPhone 7(13.3.1) Jailbreak done using Checkra1n.

Answer (score 2):

The application you are trying to install does not have a digital signature. iOS will only install applications which a valid digital signature on your phone. That's why you get the error message "No code signature found".

You can sign the application yourself if you have an iOS development account. Once the application is signed, you can install it using `ideviceinstaller`.

Alternatively, you can jailbreak your phone, which will cause iOS to no longer validate the digital signature of applications you are trying to install.